# Is there a reason std::for_each was not written to take a std::list?

Tags: c++, c++11

I realize it amounts to syntactic sugar but, with the advent of lambda, I would have loved to be able to type

```
std::for_each(list, [](Emitter& e) { e->emit() });
```

instead of

```
std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), ....);
```

I get the later is more generally usable but they could have provided both (AFAICT the former would simply be another template function)

Comment: It wasn't so easy to provide both before C++11, both meaning it supports all containers, not just `std::list`. There's a Ranges Study Group working on this, among other things.

Comment: `#define RANGE(x) (x).begin(), (x).end()` would be the nasty way to do what you're trying to do...

Comment: @tmyklebu... nasty indeed :-)

Comment: @chris... thanks... nice to know someone is thinking about it. As I mentioned below I can appreciate an axiomatic approach in the std libraries but if it results in everyone writing unnecessarily verbose code (or the template proposed by Hiura) I think it should be considered for inclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess what? You can! ;-) By defining your own `for_each` function:

```
template <class C, class F>
F for_each(C const& c, F f) {
    return std::for_each(std::begin(c), std::end(c), f);
}
```

You can see a live example here: http://ideone.com/gwGNGL

Comment: For C++11, better yet, `std::begin(c)` and `std::end(c)`. Then it'll work for plain arrays too.

Comment: It'd sure be nice if that lambda expression was inverted so it read "for each int in list"

Comment: @Brian Right! I tend to forget those free functions... code updated!

Comment: @Brian: Not `std::begin(c)`, rather `using std::begin;` followed by `begin(c)`. Same for `end` also.

Comment: @Nawaz why would you use a `using` for that? I prefer to keep things in their original namespace and prevent clash. What's your perspective here?

Comment: @Hiura: Doing it that way changes the type of lookup performed for `begin(c)` from qualified name lookup to unqualified name lookup. Unqualified name lookup includes argument-dependent lookup, so a function named `begin` in the same namespace as the type of `c` (or, sadly, the type of a template argument of the type of `c` - *this*, I think is a mistake) will be found as well as `std::begin`. This allows for better extensibility.

Comment: @HighCommander4,Nawaz : Didn't know that! Thanks for the intel, will read about it later. :-)

Comment: Why does this return `void`?

Comment: Thanks Hiura... this is exactly what I had envisioned (though I'm not sure the const restriction is necessary.) I'm tagging this as my preferred answer but props to chris for pointing out they are looking at it for future standards (my question was primarily about *why* they didn't provide it)

Answer (score 2):

With the advent of lambdas, here come range-based `for` loops as well:

```
for (auto &e: list)
    e.emit();
```

Comment: +1 -- `for_each`, barring some corner cases, is basically obsolete.  (that corner case involving code made to look like other algorithms).

Answer (score 1):

Standard algorithms work with ranges, not with containers. That's a deliberate design decision. The standard library should not be bloated. If you want to add this functionality yourself, you trivially can.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not on the Comittie, what follows is speculation.  But seems legit to me.

> Is there a reason std::for_each was not written to take a std::list?

**Code bloat.**

Providing both `for_each (begin, end)` and `for_each (container)` would have been effectively redundant.  After all, as you said, you could simply write `for_each (c.begin(), c.end())` and get exactly the behavior you want.

Since the version you propose is just syntactic sugar for, and more restrictive than the version that is part of the library (which takes `begin` and `end` iterators), there was no point in adding it.

I suppose you could think of this as an extension of the "don't pay for what you don't want" philosophy that guides much of C++'s overall design.  As mentioned eslewhere, you could very simply provide your own fairly generic function.  Here's some *psudocde* illustrating such:

```
namespace blah
{
  template <typename Cont, typename UnaryFunction> inline UnaryFunction for_each (Cont& cont, UnaryFunction f)
  {
    return std::for_each (cont.begin(), cont.end(), f);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does this return an iterator?

Comment: @K-ballo:  Oops.  Fixed.

Comment: Tighter looking code is always a good thing IMO and I'm not sure that it counts as code bloat/pay-as-you-play since the template definition (effectively what Hiura wrote was what I envisioned) is latent and hidden behind the std:: imports. Having said that. I can appreciate a more axiomatic approach in standard libraries.